# NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification on iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

While the `NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification` perfectly makes sense on Mac OS X, I don't see how you can possibly receive it on iPhone OS. In order to change the locale, you have to quit the running application, then change it in *Settings* → *General* → *International* → *Region Format*. At that point, your app is not running, so how could it receive the notification?

I first thought this notification was leftover from the Mac OS X documentation, but then I found this in [Apple Push Notification Service Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW3):

> The application might send its
>   provider the preferred language every
>   time the user changes something in the
>   current locale. To do this, you can
>   listen for the notification named
>   NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
>   and, in your notification-handling
>   method, get the code identifying the
>   preferred language and send that to
>   your provider.

So, how do you trigger this notification on iPhone OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, you don't, since you can't run any apps while the locale is being changed. In the future, you might (hint hint*).

Note that you can poll the current locale via `+[NSLocale currentLocale]` as usual.

* I am not privy to any insider info.

Comment: Yup. Setting the language kills all running app processes. Debug info in the simulator `(Timestamp here) (App name here) Terminating since there is no system app.`